# Strange crash report for iPad app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, crash

I received the following crash report from a user.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xf0012e8d
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3601cc98 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreFoundation                  0x312bdc30 CFGetRetainCount
2   QuartzCore                      0x30605c08 CA::release_root_if_unused(_CALayer*, _CALayer*, void*)
3   QuartzCore                      0x30605bb4 x_hash_table_remove_if
4   QuartzCore                      0x305e4f96 CA::Transaction::commit()
5   QuartzCore                      0x305de04e CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x312fca2e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
7   CoreFoundation                  0x312fe45e __CFRunLoopDoObservers
8   CoreFoundation                  0x312ff754 __CFRunLoopRun
9   CoreFoundation                  0x3128febc CFRunLoopRunSpecific
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3128fdc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode
11  GraphicsServices                0x32478418 GSEventRunModal
12  GraphicsServices                0x324784c4 GSEventRun
13  UIKit                           0x329f8d62 -[UIApplication _run]
14  UIKit                           0x329f6800 UIApplicationMain
15  IW Select                       0x00002b60 main + 44
16  IW Select                       0x00002b28 start + 32
```

I'm having trouble debugging it since it doesn't look like the crash was even caused by something in my app.  Does anyone know what could cause a crash like this?

Comment: Are you having animation code called from a background thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we observe the crash log, we will notice that, it was expecting some object but it was already released.(see it was calling `CFGetRetainCount` on the needed object to acertain that object is still alive, but it is not). Also, if we notice the frameworks then it indicates that crash could be because of some view is released or something related to it.(as it says its crashing during animation.)

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3601cc98 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreFoundation                  0x312bdc30 CFGetRetainCount
2   QuartzCore                      0x30605c08 CA::release_root_if_unused(_CALayer*, _CALayer*, void*)
3   QuartzCore                      0x30605bb4 x_hash_table_remove_if
4   QuartzCore                      0x305e4f96 CA::Transaction::commit()
5   QuartzCore                      0x305de04e CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x312fca2e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

This might be able to help you out or at least get you started.
[Debugging EXC_BAD_ACCESS Errors](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone)

Comment: Did you even look at the crash report?

Comment: uhm yeah. From what I can tell its an EXC_BAD_ACESS am I right? Have you looked through your Debugger. Down voting is no way of getting answers. You're on your own

Comment: 1.  As I mentioned, it is a crash report submitted by a user.  I haven't been able to reproduce the crash and therefore can't look at the debugger.
2.  It is a EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception, yes, but as I mentioned, if you look at the traceback, you will notice that my application (IW Select) appears only at the deepest level (the beginning of execution).  This is why my question was whether anyone knew what could cause such a crash (not, “how do you debug an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error?”).

Comment: I do appreciate you offering your input though.

Answer (score 0):

Check your localization settings. Specifically, change your language settings to something other than English/your default language and see if you can reproduce the crash.